# standardjs linter exclude file

Tags: javascript, command-line-interface, lint

I need to lint all project files (js) and exclude one file.

I was trying:

`standard "www\**\*.js" "!www\fileToIgnore.js"`

and

`standard ["www\**\*.js" "!www\fileToIgnore.js"]`

None of this works. Any idea?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Please add the below block to your `package.json` file to ignore the files that you don't want to include while linting,

```
"standard": {
  "ignore": [
    "/www/**/*.js"
  ]
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: how can achieve this, but using cli?

Comment: found it.. with this `standard \"$(pwd)/src/**/*[!spec].ts\"` you can ignore everything that includes 'spec'